# how to reload a page only once react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a page that I need to refresh, but only one time after it loads. If I put `window.location.reload` in `useeffect()`, then it refreshes an infinite amount of times. How do I make it stop reloading the page after one time? I tried boolean values and other stuff but nothing works. It keeps refreshing an infinite amount of times. The route which is linking to page is market.

app.tsx

```
   import React from "react";
    import Market from "containers/Market";
    import Coins from "containers/Coins";
    import PoweredBy from "components/PoweredBy";
    import MarketProvider from "store/MarketProvider";
    import Exchanges from "components/Exchanges";
    import Exchange from "components/Exchange";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
    import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
    import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
    
    import { default as Tab, TabProps } from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
    import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';
    import CodeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Code';
    import TimelineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Timeline';
    
    
    
    const LinkTab: React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps> = Tab as React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps>;
    
    function NavBar() {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    
      // console.log(value);
    
    
      const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      };
    
      return (
      <div >
      <AppBar position="static">
               <Tabs>
                   <Tab label="Exchanges" to="/exchange" component={Link}  />
                   <Tab label="Coins" to="/" component={Link}  />
                   <Tab label="Home" to="/pm" component={Link}  />
               </Tabs>
         </AppBar>
      </div>
    )
    };
    
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <NavBar  />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Coins} />
              <Route exact path="/exchange" component={Exchanges} />
              <Route exact path="/market"  >
               <MarketProvider>
                 <Market />
               </MarketProvider>
             </Route>
              <Redirect from="/" to="/" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    };
```

file.tsx

```
 import React from "react";
    import { Grid, Snackbar, SnackbarCloseReason } from "@material-ui/core";
    import { Skeleton, Alert } from "@material-ui/lab";
    import useAxios from "axios-hooks";
    import PrimaryChart from "components/PrimaryChart";
    import SecondaryChart from "components/SecondaryChart";
    import TimeFilterButtons from "components/TimeFilterButtons";
    import { SC } from "./styled";
    import { DataProps } from "interfaces/DataProps";
    import useWindowDimensions from "hooks/useWindowDimensions";
    import { useQueryParams, StringParam } from "use-query-params";
    import { MarketContext } from "store/MarketProvider";
    var x = true;
    const Market = () => {
      const {
        filteredDataState: { filteredData },
      } = React.useContext(MarketContext);
    
    
      const [queryParams] = useQueryParams({
        id: StringParam,
        name: StringParam,
      });
      const [timeFilter, setTimeFilter] = React.useState<string>("1");
      const [isErrorMessage, setIsErrorMessage] = React.useState<string>("");
      const [boxWidth, setBoxWidth] = React.useState<number>(0);
      const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
      const [{ data, loading, error }, fetch] = useAxios(
        {
          url: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${queryParams?.id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=${timeFilter}`,
          method: "GET",
        },
        { manual: true }
      );
      const gridItemRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (queryParams.id && queryParams.name) {
          fetch();
        }
      }, [fetch, queryParams, queryParams.id, queryParams.name]);
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
          setIsErrorMessage(error.message);
        }
      }, [error]);
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = (width?: number) => {
          setBoxWidth(width || 0);
    
    
    
        };
    
        handleResize(gridItemRef.current?.clientWidth || 0);
    
        window.addEventListener("resize", () =>
          handleResize(gridItemRef?.current?.clientWidth || 0)
        );
    
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("resize", () => handleResize());
        };
      }, [gridItemRef]);
    
      const mappedData: DataProps[] = React.useMemo(() => {
        return data
          ? data?.prices.map((ele: any) => ({
              date: new Date(ele[0]),
              price: ele[1],
            }))
          : [];
      }, [data]);
    
      const handleError = (
        e: React.SyntheticEvent<any>,
        reason?: SnackbarCloseReason
      ) => {
        setIsErrorMessage("");
      };
    
      return (
        <Grid container justify="center">
          <Grid ref={gridItemRef} item xs={12} md={10} lg={8}>
            <SC.MarketHeader>
              <SC.Title>{queryParams?.name}</SC.Title>
              <TimeFilterButtons
                value={timeFilter}
                onChange={(v) => setTimeFilter(v || "")}
              />
            </SC.MarketHeader>
            {loading ? (
              <Skeleton
                variant="rect"
                height={Math.floor(height * 0.6)}
                width={boxWidth}
              />
            ) : mappedData?.length ? (
              <>
                <PrimaryChart
                  data={filteredData ?? []}
                  height={Math.floor(height * 0.4)}
                  width={boxWidth}
                  margin={{
                    top: 16,
                    right: 16,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 48,
                  }}
                />
                <SecondaryChart
                  data={mappedData ?? []}
                  height={Math.floor(height * 0.1)}
                  width={boxWidth}
                  margin={{
                    top: 0,
                    right: 16,
                    bottom: 24,
                    left: 48,
                  }}
                />
              </>
            ) : null}
          </Grid>
          <Snackbar open={!!isErrorMessage} onClose={handleError}>
            <Alert onClose={handleError} severity="error">
              {isErrorMessage}
            </Alert>
          </Snackbar>
        </Grid>
      );
    };
    
    export default Market;
```

Comment: Whats the reason why you need it to reload? Kind of defeats the purpose of needing react.

Comment: Please add the reason for the reload to your question so we can understand the context a little bit better.

Comment: reason is because data onlyupdatets after refreshing page

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason of reloading bth but I'm thinking if you do conditional rendering and handle with boolean when should reload that's would be ok

something like:

`const [hasAlreadyReload, setHasAlreadyReload] = React.useState(false);`

...

`hasAlreadyReload && <Redirect from="/" to="/" />`